# Как вывести на экран все числа из массива с помощью стримов?

Tags: java

У меня проблема со стримами, мне нужно вывести на экран все числа из массива строк, но я просто не могу понять как это сделать с помощью стримов.

Дан массив строк `String numbers = filterAndCollectByJoining("1", "a", "2", "b", "3", "c");`

```
private static String filterAndCollectByJoining(String... strings) {
    return Arrays.stream(strings)
            .map(String::toCharArray)
            .filter(chars -> Character.isDigit(chars))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(filterAndCollectByJoining("1", "a", "2", "b", "3", "c")); //1,2,3
}

public static String filterAndCollectByJoining(String... strings) {
    return Arrays.stream(strings)
            .filter(chars -> Character.isDigit(chars.charAt(0)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: Да, но возвращаемые значения и метод main менять нельзя

Comment: Задача звучит так: Перепишіть код методу filterAndCollectByJoining в одну строку використовуючи Stream API.

Comment: @Vadym изменил код

Comment: дай бог тебе здоровья, добрый человек

Comment: Спасибо) Если ответ помог, отметьте его как решение